# IDFA / ASIdentifierManager not found

Tags: ios, objective-c, idfa

```
if ( NSClassFromString(@"ASIdentifierManager"))
    {
        limitAdTracking = !ASIdentifierManager.sharedManager.advertisingTrackingEnabled;
        idfa = [ASIdentifierManager.sharedManager.advertisingIdentifier UUIDString];
        userDict[@"limit_ad_tracking"] = @(limitAdTracking);
    }
```

I have SDK. This sdk uses in different apps. But sometimes My SDK doesn`t get idfa. It can happen in one version of application (one time I get, one time - nope). What can happen?

Comment: do you mean that you run the app on a device and the ASIdentifierManager get found. then, you stop the app and run it again at the same device and boom it's not there?!

Comment: No. I mean that I see that one version of application (app of my client) sometime sent idfa in request but sometime - no. And I can not find a reason of this.

Comment: why do you check if ASIdentifierManager exists? do you support iOS version prior to 6.0?

Comment: In request I get version of iOS. Sometime it is 7.x and sometime it is 8.x

Comment: do you get an empty advertisingIdentifier or zeros and dashes 00000000000-000000-0000? something like that.

Comment: No. NSClassFromString(@"ASIdentifierManager")  == nil

Answer (score 1):

If your App was not linked against AdSupport.framework, then `NSClassFromString(@"ASIdentifierManager")` will return `nil` and you'll never get the IDFA.

Is it possible you added/removed AdSupport.framework between the versions that exhibit different behavior?